# how to solve error appears because of xlim in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The following MatLab code I am using to plot the graph:

```
path1 = '/DATA/sanjay/VT-GAN-master/new_Results_for_diverse_features/nm_to_nm/';
list1 = dir(path1);
fName1 = {list1.name};
[~,y1]=size(fName1);
path1
vector = [];
title = {'000','018','036','054','072','090','108','126','144','162','180'};
title = categorical(title);
x_axis = {'01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10'};
x_axis = categorical(x_axis);
mat1 = [];
for num1=3:y1
    path2 = char(strcat(path1,fName1(num1)));
    data = readtable(path2);
    data = data{:,:};    
    mat1 = [mat1;mean(data)];
end
mat1

data01 = mat1(:,1);
data02 = mat1(:,2);
data03 = mat1(:,3);
data04 = mat1(:,4);
data05 = mat1(:,5);
data06 = mat1(:,6);
data07 = mat1(:,7);
data08 = mat1(:,8);
data09 = mat1(:,9);
data10 = mat1(:,10);
data11 = mat1(:,11);

figure,
plot(x_axis,data01,'-+',x_axis,data02,'-*',x_axis,data03,'-o',x_axis,data04,'-x',x_axis,data05,'-s',x_axis,data06,'-d',x_axis,data07,'-p',x_axis,data08,'-h',x_axis,data09,'-^',x_axis,data10,'->',x_axis,data11,'-<','linewidth',2,'MarkerSize',12);
xlim([1 10])
lgd = legend('Probe angle: 000','Probe angle: 018','Probe angle: 036','Probe angle: 054','Probe angle: 072','Probe angle: 090','Probe angle: 108','Probe angle: 126','Probe angle: 144', 'Probe angle: 162','Probe angle: 180');
lgd.FontSize = 18;
lbx = xlabel('Rank from one to ten for nm to nm gallery and probe set','fontname','times');
lby = ylabel('Average accuracy in percentage (%)','fontname','times') ;
lbx.FontSize = 18;
lby.FontSize = 18;
set(gca,'FontWeight','bold')
```

But I am getting the following error because of xlim:

```
Error using xlim (line 31)
Value must be a 2-element vector of increasing or equal categorical values as ordered by the ruler Categories property.

Error in Rank_based_Curv (line 34)
xlim([1 10])
```

how do I limit the index from 01 to 10 and remove the extra parts from both sides on the X axis?

Comment: Your x-axis is a `categorical` array and you're trying to set its bounds do some numeric values, it's not clear (to MATLAB) how you expect this to work, the two are not comparable.  This is described in the error message. You maybe want to create an [ordinal categorical](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html#bt0v6xw-3)

Comment: I know and understand that but to define the argument inside the xlim([ ?   ? ]) that I don't know. Please specify the arguments

Comment: Did you visit the documentation I linked? If you define the categorical as ordinal then I think your existing syntax might work